# Compare multiple columns with each other to calculate association

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below with 100 columns like this:

```
Product A   Product B   Product C ....
1               1               1
1               0               1
0               1               1
0               0               0
1               1               1
0               0               0
```

I want to see how many Customers who buys Product A also buys product B, so on
for e.g. out of 3 customers who buys product A , 2 buys product B, so the result is calculated as
2/3 = 0.6667

```
          B 
        No  Yes 
A   Yes 1   2    - Result 0.666666667
```

Similarly, we will do for A - C

```
          C
        No  Yes 
A   Yes 0   3    - Result 1
```

My Expected Output is

```
Combination    Result               
A-B             0.66            
A-C             1           
B-A             ..
B-C             ..
C-A             ..
C-B             ..
```

I am using `pandas.groupby()` and looping over different columns. Is there's an efficient way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@` for matrix multiplication, which computes the co-occurrence for you:

```
(df.T @ df)/df.sum()
```

Output:

```
           Product A  Product B  Product C
Product A   1.000000   0.666667       0.75
Product B   0.666667   1.000000       0.75
Product C   1.000000   1.000000       1.00
```

Comment: thank you so much @Quang Hong. the execution is faster now, is it possible I can get the dataframe as mentioned in my expected output, if not that's fine. Already accepted your answer

Comment: Chain that with `stack().reset_index()` and play with the out put.

Comment: Yes, filter out those rows have the same level values.